# How to assert image present in selenium python web driver?

Tags: python, image, selenium, webdriver, assert

I want to assert that an image is present on a page.
I'm using selenium web driver with python.
I also want a message printed when the image has not been loaded.
Can anyone help me with a script?

Here is a piece of html code that displays an image on a website: 
[img src='photo.jpg' class='image class']

Comment: xpath selector, `img[src='photo.jpg']`

Answer (score 2):

I can't help with python, but can give a general suggestion and Java code for those who are looking to do something similar in Java. My approach would be

1. Get the `src` attribute of the image and make a quick `HTTP GET`
   call and make sure you get `200 OK` response.
2. Once thats done, you
       could check the `naturalWidth`attribute of the WebElement using
       Javascript. If its more than 0, its rendered fine. However this
       works differently in IE. IE has `.complete` attribute. It will be
       true if the image is rendered (Reference [here](http://watirmelon.com/2012/11/27/checking-an-image-is-actually-visible-using-webdriver/))

Here is sample Java code,

```
@Test
   public void test()
   {
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      String url = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/";
      driver.get(url);
      WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='ESPN Cricinfo']>img"));
      String src = img.getAttribute("src");
      Client client = Client.create();
      WebResource resource = client.resource(src);
      assertThat("Response code is not 200 OK", resource.get(ClientResponse.class).getStatus(), equalTo(200));
      assertThat("Image is not rendered correctly", isImageVisible(driver, img),equalTo(true));
      driver.quit();
   }
   public boolean isImageVisible(WebDriver driver, WebElement image)
   {
      Boolean result = null;
      if (driver instanceof InternetExplorerDriver || ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserName().equals("internet explorer"))
      {
         result = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].complete;", image);
      }
      else
      { //other browser types use diff method to check
         result = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return (typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth!=\"undefined\" && arguments[0].naturalWidth>0);", image);
      }
      return result.booleanValue();
   }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged as "python".

Comment: I know. I mentioned I couldn't help in python but gave general advise that can be implemented in python. Provided Java code just in case if someone accidentally comes here and needs a Java solution. Just trying to help

Comment: Sure, I understand. This is why I'm here too. I see the points about my answer too, but I left it until the OP says it helps or not, or if the OP needs more help.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to do this but I decided to retrieve all the image tags.

```
all_images = self.driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('img')")
for image in range(0, len(all_images)):
    print self.driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('img')[{}].src".format(image))
```

Answer (score 0):

Left out driver setup but this should work once you add yours in. Partial credit to Nilesh for pointing me in right direction with his Java example.

```
import requests
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def setUp(self):
    self.verificationErrors = []


def test_images_for_200_response(self):
    driver.get('http:example.com')
    example_images = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')

    for image in example_images:
        current_link = image.get_attribute("src")
        r = requests.get(current_link)
        try: self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
        except AssertionError, e: self.verificationErrors.append(current_link + ' delivered response code of ' + r.status_code)

def tearDown(self):
    driver.quit()
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
```